# How to run a slurm job array that iterates over a number of files

Tags: slurm

I would like to run an sbatch script where I input a directory

```
sbatch --export=dir=/path/to/dir script.sh
```

and the script submits N array jobs where N is the number of files in `/path/to/dir`

My script.sh looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=array_job
#SBATCH --output=%j.out
#SBATCH --error=%j.err

# Generate the list of files using ls command
files=($(ls $dir/*.txt))

# Get the number of files
num_files=${#files[@]}

# Set the array size
#SBATCH --array=1-$num_files

# Get the file for this array task
current_file=${files[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID-1]}

# do something
touch $(basename $current_file)
```

However this code seems to only process the last file in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted the sbatch script to be dynamic i.e. not having to hardwire the array size. Also I didn't want to have to generate extra files. I admit that, as @Poshi points out, this will break if the number of files changes during execution.

The solution that solved my problem is

```
sbatch --export=search=*.txt --array=0-$(ls *.txt | wc -l) script.sh
```

Then script.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=array_job
#SBATCH --output=%j.out
#SBATCH --error=%j.err

# Generate a list of files from the search term
files=($(eval "ls ${search}"))

# Get specific file for this array task
current_file=${files[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID-1]}

# do something
touch $(basename $current_file)
```

`search` can then be anything e.g. `../some/dir/???.txt` as long as the same phrase is used to set the array length

Answer (score 0):

From `man sbatch`:

```
sbatch will stop processing further #SBATCH directives once the first non-comment non-whitespace line has been reached in the script.
```

So when you are trying to set the `--array` parameter, it is too late. You must specify the `--array` parameter before any script command.

You should get that number beforehand and set it in the script. You should also fix the files to process, otherwise the sorting or the number of files in the folder of interest could change while running the job array:

```
$ ls $dir/*.txt > file_list
$ wc -l file_list
666
```

Whose script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=array_job
#SBATCH --output=%j.out
#SBATCH --error=%j.err

# Set the array size
#SBATCH --array=1-666

# Generate the list of files using ls command
readarray -t files <file_list

# Get the number of files
num_files=${#files[@]}

# Get the file for this array task
current_file=${files[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID-1]}

# do something
touch $(basename $current_file)
```

Alternatively, you could do something similar, but on the fly. Using a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=array_job
#SBATCH --output=%j.out
#SBATCH --error=%j.err

# Generate the list of files using ls command
readarray -t files <file_list

# Get the number of files
num_files=${#files[@]}

# Get the file for this array task
current_file=${files[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID-1]}

# do something
touch $(basename $current_file)
```

Launch it as:

```
$ ls $dir/*.txt > file_list
$ sbatch --array=1-$(wc -l file_list) script.sh
```